# How can I count how many times a unique row appeared in my google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to count how many times a unique row appeared in my sheets?

Here's a sample link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z036Q4RtfYPyO0JdcJ9Fcb-adundFdzijNG_1ehsT-4/edit?usp=sharing

I need to count how many times "Apple | 10 | 9 | 1" and "Orange | 12 | 10 | 2" appeared.

I tried using this:

={UNIQUE(A2:D8, false), ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(A2:D8, UNIQUE(A2:D8)))}

However, it counts individual unique cells, not the whole row.

Comment: Please share a link to a sample spreadsheet with data already entered. Otherwise, the volunteer contributors here would have to set up our own sheet and enter your sample data before even beginning to write a solution. In your sheet, be clear about how and where you want the results to appear by *hand-entering* the results as you want a formula to return them.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the spreadsheet, Allen. However, I don't see where you *hand-entered* the results you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:D, "Select A, B, C, D, count(D) where A <>'' group by A, B, C, D label count(D) 'Count'", 1)
```